# how to open firstVC to tab bar controller in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

i am Embeb in Tab Bar Controller in secondVC.
i am trying to open firstVC to secondVC in Tab Bar Controller.

i have create button in programmatically in firstVC.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "SecondSegue")
        {
            var secondvc: SecondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC

        }
    }
```

[image]

i want to open firstVC to `TabBarController` in SecondVC

please help me.

Comment: Your storyboard diagram doesn't look to be valid (`UITabBarController`s aren't strictly speaking allowed as part of a `UINavigationController` stack). Perhaps you meant to have a scene such as: http://i.imgur.com/JS0g4Gn.png

Comment: i want open firstVC to tabbarController not i don't want to tabbarcontroller in firstVC @Robert